# Need help with $(¬p \vee ¬(p\wedge¬q)) \wedge ¬(p \wedge q) ≡¬p$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

Hey guys I just need help solving this solution here. Sorry if I didn't type the symbols correctly.

My solution so far:
$$
(¬p \vee ¬(p\wedge¬q)) \wedge (¬p \vee ¬q)≡
(¬p \vee (¬p \vee q)) \wedge (¬p \vee ¬q)≡
$$
at this point I'm stuck. Is there any way I can take care of the not-$p$ $\vee$ not-$p$?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that would be Idempotent Law:
\begin{align*}
(\neg p \lor \neg p \lor q) \land (\neg p \lor \neg q)
&\equiv (\neg p \lor q) \land (\neg p \lor \neg q) \\
&\equiv \neg p \lor (q \land \neg q) \\
&\equiv \neg p \lor \bot \\
&\equiv \neg p \\
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align*}
&(¬p \vee (¬p \vee q)) \wedge (¬p \vee ¬q) \\
&\equiv((\lnot p \lor q) \land (\lnot p \lor \lnot q)) \\
&\equiv\lnot p \lor(q \land  \lnot q)) \\
&\equiv\lnot p
\end{align*}

Comment: how did you manage to remove the two qs in line 3?

Comment: It's the distributive law.